# Output Inserted T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This might be a noob question, but I am very much not familiar with how the `OUTPUT` clause of an `INSERT` works in SQL Server.

**Problem**

I am inserting values into a table and I would like to generate a unique id for that operation. Previously I used the following code to generate a unique id:

```
select top 1 id 
from [dbo].[TEP_Payments_Table] 
order by id desc + 1
```

The issue with this is some users can have duplicate id's if they use the form at the same time.

**Solution**

With much research, I came across `Output Inserted` that apparently solves this problem.

To do this, I have created the following table:

- `TEP_ReceiptID` - where column `ReceiptID` is id col and primary key.

I then attempted to use "Output Inserted" into my usual Insert statement, code:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TEP_Payments_Table] ([col1], [col2]) 
VALUES
OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO dbo.TEP_ReceiptID
('testval1', 'testval2')
```

To my disappointment, this does not work. Again, my fault as I am not familiar with this `Output` syntax.

I would very much appreciate it if you inform me where I have gone wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The typical code is:

```
declare @ids table (id int);

insert into [dbo].[TEP_Payments_Table] ([col1], [col2]) 
    output inserted.id into @ids
    values ('testval1', 'testval2');
```

Your version would probably work if the `output` clause were before the `values` clause.

Comment: Of course... Quick question on your code. This table you are declaring, is it newly created everytime this code is executed? Or is it a table already created in advance?

Comment: @OdaySalim . . . A table variable is created every time the code runs.